# How to create a function that displays a table with the appropriate fields, using a cursor to go through each skill and calculate the gap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a function that displays a table with the appropriate fields, using a cursor to go through each skill and calculate the gap between expected level and assessed level. I'm not too sure this is correct, but this is what I've written so far. The cursor gets data from several tables and puts it into the created variables, then when the cursor is open it calculates the gap.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis] 
(@username nvarchar(100) ,@employee_id int ,@org_id int ) 
returns @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis table (
id int,
employee_id int,
skill_id int,
skill_description NVARCHAR(100),
expected_level_id int,
expected_level_rank int,
expected_level_text nvarchar(100),
expectedstd_level_id int,
expectedstd_level_rank int,
expectedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
assessed_level_id   INT,
assessed_level_text nvarchar(100),
assessed_level_rank int,
assessedstd_level_id int,
assessedstd_level_rank int,
assessedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
gap int
)
BEGIN 
DECLARE
@gap int,
@skill_id int,
@skill_description NVARCHAR(100),
@expected_level_id int,
@expected_level_rank int,
@expected_level_text nvarchar(100),
@expectedstd_level_id int,
@expectedstd_level_rank int,
@expectedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
@assessed_level_id   INT,
@assessed_level_text nvarchar(100),
@assessed_level_rank int,
@assessedstd_level_id int,
@assessedstd_level_rank int,
@assessedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
@standard_check int


SET NOCOUNT ON

declare wf_list_of_employee_skills cursor STATIC FOR
SELECT employee_id,skill_id,b.description,expected_level_id,c.ranking,c.description,c.id,d.ranking,d.description,assessed_level_id,e.description,e.ranking,e.id,f.ranking,f.description FROM cmp_v2_competency_employee_chart a left join cmp_v2_skillgroups_def b on a.skill_id =b.id 
left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_details c on a.expected_level_id = c.id left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_standard_def d on a.expected_level_id = d.id 
left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_details e on a.assessed_level_id = e.id left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_standard_def f on a.assessed_level_id = f.id
where a.employee_id=@employee_id and a.org_id=@org_id

open wf_list_of_employee_skills  
fetch next from wf_list_of_employee_skills into @employee_id,@skill_id,@skill_description,@expected_level_id,@expected_level_rank,@expected_level_text,@expectedstd_level_id,@expectedstd_level_rank,@assessed_level_id,@assessed_level_text,@assessed_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_id,@assessedstd_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_text

while @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN

if @expected_level_rank > @assessed_level_rank 
begin
select @gap = (@expected_level_rank - @assessed_level_rank)
end
insert into @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis (employee_id,skill_id,skill_description,expected_level_id,expected_level_rank,expected_level_text,expectedstd_level_id,expectedstd_level_rank,assessed_level_id,assessed_level_text,assessed_level_rank,assessedstd_level_id,assessedstd_level_rank,assessedstd_level_text,gap)
values (@employee_id,@skill_id,@skill_description,@expected_level_id,@expected_level_rank,@expected_level_text,@expectedstd_level_id,@expectedstd_level_rank,@assessed_level_id,@assessed_level_text,@assessed_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_id,@assessedstd_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_text,@gap)
select * from @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis
fetch next from wf_list_of_employee_skills into @employee_id,@skill_id,@skill_description,@expected_level_id,@expected_level_rank,@expected_level_text,@expectedstd_level_id,@expectedstd_level_rank,@assessed_level_id,@assessed_level_text,@assessed_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_id,@assessedstd_level_rank,@assessedstd_level_text

END
close wf_list_of_employee_skills
deallocate wf_list_of_employee_skills
return
end
GO
```

Comment: This can't work. In your second `fetch next` you're not overwriting the variables (`@expected_level_rank` etc.), so in your `while` loop you're always using the same values. What are the variables `@value_required` and `@value_actual`? They are not even declared anywhere.

Comment: I have removed the mysql tag, and added the sql-server tag (going by the syntax used). Please make sure you know what database system you're using, and apply the correct tags when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no need for a cursor - you *almost never* need a cursor, and they tend to be very slow. I might have some details wrong (hard to test without the actual tables set up) but should be close:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis] 
(@username nvarchar(100) ,@employee_id int ,@org_id int ) 
returns @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis table (
id int,
employee_id int,
skill_id int,
skill_description NVARCHAR(100),
expected_level_id int,
expected_level_rank int,
expected_level_text nvarchar(100),
expectedstd_level_id int,
expectedstd_level_rank int,
expectedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
assessed_level_id   INT,
assessed_level_text nvarchar(100),
assessed_level_rank int,
assessedstd_level_id int,
assessedstd_level_rank int,
assessedstd_level_text nvarchar(100),
gap int
)
BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis
SELECT a.employee_id,
    a.skill_id,
    b.description,
    a.expected_level_id,
    c.ranking AS expected_level_rank,
    c.description AS expected_level_text,
    d.id AS expectedstd_level_id,
    d.ranking AS expectedstd_level_rank,
    d.description AS expectedstd_level_text,
    a.assessed_level_id AS assessed_level_id,
    e.description AS assessed_level_text,
    e.ranking AS asessed_level_rank,
    e.id AS assessedstd_level_id,
    f.ranking AS assessedstd_level_rank,
    f.description AS assessedstd_level_text,
    c.ranking - e.ranking AS gap
FROM cmp_v2_competency_employee_chart a 
LEFT JOIN cmp_v2_skillgroups_def b on a.skill_id =b.id 
left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_details c on a.expected_level_id = c.id 
LEFT join cmp_v2_competency_levels_standard_def d on a.expected_level_id = d.id 
left join cmp_v2_competency_levels_details e on a.assessed_level_id = e.id 
LEFT join cmp_v2_competency_levels_standard_def f on a.assessed_level_id = f.id
where a.employee_id=@employee_id and a.org_id=@org_id
AND c.ranking > e.ranking;

end
GO
```

Comment: You also don't need a multi-statement function, you could so this as an inline Table Valued function, which is much faster. Just change `returns @competency_levels_skill_gap_analysis table (...` to `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT a.employeeid...`